# Why doesn't try/catch work in Matlab when the Image Acquisition Toolbox drops frames?

Tags: exception, try-catch, matlab

I am using Matlab's Image Acquisition Toolbox to acquire high-speed video over gigabit Ethernet. I'm having some trouble with frame-dropping, but that's not what this question is about. What I really want to do is tell Matlab to *continue running the script* even after encountering the frame-dropping error.

I used a try/catch statement for this purpose but it just doesn't work. Here is my code, sparing some of the details relating to setting up the camera and using the data:

```
%% setting up camera
while(1)
    % continue acquiring data forever

    while(vidObj.FramesAvailable < vidObj.FramesPerTrigger)
        % wait until we're ready to get the data
        try
            pause(.1)
        catch exception
            disp "i got an error"
        end
    end

    % get the data
    [img, t] = getdata(vidObj);

    %% do something with the data
    %% ...
end
```

What happens is that, every once in a while, some frames are dropped and the toolbox raises an error. *This happens inside the try block, but Matlab raises an exception anyway!* The output looks something like:

```
Error event occurred at 21:08:20 for video input object: Mono8-gige-1.
gige: Block/frame 1231 is being dropped beecause a lost packet is unable to be resent....

Error in script_name (line 82)
    pause(.1)
```

You can see that the error occurs while we're waiting to collect data (the "pause" statement), which is inside the try block, and yet the exception is not caught correctly because my debugging message doesn't print and the program grinds to a halt.

How can I get Matlab to observe the try/catch structure and continue after this error happens?

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure that the error isn't actually occurring on the `pause`. The vidObj is waiting in the background, when the pause occurs, it has a chance to run itself, and that's when the error occurs. You'll have to find the actual code in the vidObj that is erroring out. I hope this helps...

Comment: I think you could be right, but the code for vidObj is buried in the ImageAcquisitionToolbox somewhere. I wouldn't even know where to start looking, and they may not have even made the source code available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The error message is not a true error, but more of a warning. Execution does not stop. However, vidObj stops collecting frames and my code keeps looping forever, waiting for enough frames to be collected.

You can insert a check for this condition like so:

```
% wait until enough frames are available
while(vidObj.FramesAvailable < vidObj.FramesPerTrigger)
    pause(.1)

    if strcmp(vidObj.Running, 'off')
        % It has stopped running, probably because frames were dropped
        start(vidObj)
    end
end
```

Now, upon frame dropping, the object will be restarted and acquistion continues. Obviously the dropped frames cannot be recovered so there will be a gap in the video.